# Can a Tesla Powerwall 2 be rate limited?

Tags: electrical-engineering, battery, renewable-energy, solar-energy, energy-storage

Can a telsa powerwall 2 be rate limited (discharge/charge)?

I have access to realtime electricity rates (30 min update interval) and also access to 12 hour predicted look ahead. So I wish to limit the charging (if the buyback rate is high) and limit the discharging (if the buyback rate is low).

I can see that I can basically just use an on/off controller by literally shutting the powerwall off entirely (the api supports this). But it would be nicer to rate limit it.

Is there any public (or private) api that could allow me to achieve this?

edit: I found this API however it doesn't appear to have figured out any rate limiting. [Tesla Powerwall 2 - Local Gateway API documentation](https://github.com/vloschiavo/powerwall2)

Comment: Tesla strikes me as the type of company that would want to enable arbitrage like this.  Have you contacted them to ask?

Comment: Is that a retail electricity account that gives you 12-hour look-ahead, or a commercial account? Can I ask who the supplier is? I'm particularly interested in that sort of arrangement.

Comment: Do you have the means to simply shut off the powerwall's grid connection and are you generating your own power to feed the powerwall as well?  What do you mean by "shutting the powerwall off entirely"?

Comment: No I don't have any additional hardware. The plan was the control it via the Ethernet api which provides a full shutdown ability. If it is shutdown it won't charge or discharge