# Turbocharger boost control using two valves with a vac and boost reference for wide boost control range

Tags: control-engineering, pressure, turbomachinery

[image: oc]

Can someone explain how the above boost control setup would work. The valve on the left uses a vac source applied to the top of the diaphram which would effectively help hold the spring closed at high boost levels providing high boost than a single valve setup would. I assume this would be used to give a large boost control range (similar to a CO2 boost controller). Is this correct?

I'm not sure what the D port on the actuator does though, I assume that D and E are both connected and would both work against the spring opening it?

What control circuit would be required to drive the two valves. Would you need a split range controller with two different duty curves, or could you run them from a single controller with a single curve, eg run the two valves from a single PWM output?

Comment: Cross posted here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/69632/10976

Comment: Yeah I re-posted it here as it is more suited to engineering.

Comment: Important info on the cross post is that the car is a skoda 1.9 ...

Comment: Mike do you reply to every single post on this stack exchange?

Comment: No, do you post on every one?

Comment: You just seem to reply to every thing I've ever posted here...

Comment: I missed this one : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/26309/10902